# Flutter Calendar localization

Tags: flutter, localization, calendar

how are you?
I have a problem to do localization flutter calendar to Mexico spanish.
When I click the calendar button with locale('es') for calendar, I can see error on emulator that is "No MaterialLocalization found. DatePickerDialog widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor........".

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();


  late DateFormat _dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');
  
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    // final context = MySingletonClass.getInstance().context;
    // final Locale? locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      locale: const Locale('pl','PL'),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: Colors.blue, 
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    
  }
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final appBarHeight = screenHeight * 0.09;
    // bool _isCompositionButtonVisible = true;

    return CupertinoApp(

      //locale:const Locale('es','MX'),
      localizationsDelegates:[
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,

      ],
      supportedLocales:[
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('es','MX'),
        // Locale('en'),
        // Locale('MX'),
      ],
      locale: const Locale('pl','PL'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home:
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:  Colors.white,
      body:
          ListView(
        children: [
          

          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.11,
            child: Padding(
              child: Row(
                children: [

                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        width:300,
                        child:Text( 'fecha de nacimiento',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: label_color,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Expanded(
                    child:
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _dateFormat.format(_selectedDate);
                          _selectDate(context);
                        //   showDatePicker(
                        //     context: context,
                        //     initialDate: _selectedDate,
                        //
                        //     firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                        //     lastDate: DateTime(2199),
                        //     //locale: const Locale('es', 'MX'),
                        //   );
                         });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Text(
                              DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_selectedDate.toLocal()),
                              // _selectedDate.to,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
          
        ],
      ),
    ),
   );
  }
 }
```